# move tkinter listbox curser with item being shifted?

Tags: python-2.7, select, tkinter, listbox

Running python 2.7.8 with Tkinter.  I have a function that shifts a listbox item.  This function works.  However, I want to also move the listbox selection (ie, the indicator for the thing getting shifted).

My shift function is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091222/changing-order-of-items-in-tkinter-listbox).
Here's the list before:
[before_shift_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tefYE.jpg)
and after calling the function:
[after_shift_function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRjrS.jpg)

How can I 'slave' the selection to my shifts?? Thx

```
def shift_sel_up(seltext):
    posList = data_list.curselection()
    if not posList: # exit if nothing selected
       return

    for pos in posList:
        if pos == 0:
            my_status_update('Item at top of list.')
            continue
        text = data_list.get(pos)
        data_list.delete(pos)
        data_list.insert(pos -1, text)
# new, doesn't work - [from here][4].
#        data_list.selection_clear()
        data_list.selection_set(pos)
    return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `activate(index)` will do the trick. This will set the item at the given index to the active item (gives it the underline).

```
data_list.activate(pos -1)
```

You also need to add the `-1` for selection_set as well

```
data_list.selection_set(pos -1)
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks very much!!