# Python Tkinter list box index number

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import Tkinter

top = Tk()

Lb1 = Listbox(top)
Lb1.insert(4, "Python")
Lb1.insert(2, "Perl")
Lb1.insert(3, "C")
Lb1.insert(1, "PHP")
Lb1.insert(5, "JSP")
Lb1.insert(6, "Ruby")

Lb1.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

I have a tkinter program here how do I get PHP to the top of the list
Basicly I want them sorted by index number
Thanks in advance!
**There is a question very like mine but I want them in order automatically**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13091222/changing-order-of-items-in-tkinter-listbox), it looks like maniputating the order of items in a Listbox is hard.

Thus, if you want the items sorted programmatically, it looks like your best option is to sort them inside a python list, then insert them into the Listbox.

```
l = []
# append tuples to the list
l.append((4, "Python"))
l.append((2, "Perl"))
l.append((3, "C"))
l.append((1, "PHP"))
l.append((5, "JSP"))
l.append((6, "Ruby"))

# add to listbox in sorted order
for index, language in sorted(l):
    Lb1.insert(index, language)
```

Comment: That will do!, great to have things organised.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of "hard". Deleting an item and inserting it where you want it doesn't seem hard, and sorting items before inserting them doesn't seem hard either.